# Parsing values from TOP command and then add them up

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, virtual-machine, cpu-usage

I am having problems with the TOP command output for the average CPU load in my Virtual Machine. It shows wrong values, for instance in a VM with **1 Virtual Core** the %Cpu0 shows 3% usage while I see a process that consumes 98%.

The interesting thing is that sometimes it does work correctly. For instance, when the consuming process' user is the VM or Root. But when I do a POST request on a running owncloud instance on my VM, with JMeter, a new process appears in the VM that uses up cpu and is executed by the user "www-data". Somehow this process' usage does not show up in the average cpu load. The cpu definitely gets used as I can see the usage go up in my Virtual Machine Monitor.

(Unfortunately I cannot post a screenshot yet)

That's why I want to parse the CPU usage of each process that is shown in TOP and then add up the values to calculate the total amount of CPU usage myself to get an accurate result.

(After I run my measurement script I will end up with a top_VM.txt file that is simply a TOP log from my VM, so I want to start from there)

So far I got this:

```
awk '{ print $9 }' /home/user/top_VM.txt
```

This will give me the relevant row but I have no idea how to iterate through it save the values as variables and add them up. I would appreciate your ideas.

Best regards

Comment: If you know nodejs you can use this package https://github.com/sweetim/linux-top-parser to parse the output then you can do anything you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your 9th column in /home/user/top_VM.txt containts number like this :

10

12.5

0

0.5

...

you can do :

```
awk '{ sum+=$9} END {print sum}' /home/user/top_VM.txt
```

if your 9th column dont contains only number you can do :

```
#The first awk is to get only number part (12.3 from 12.3%cpu)
awk '{printf ("%f\n",$9)} ' /home/user/top_VM.txt | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum} '
```

in order to calculate cpu % for each one of your snapshots you can use the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
count="0"
VM="VM cpu usage : "
SUM="ONSTART"

 while read line ; 
 do
     #extract the first word in each line
     TMP=$(echo $line | awk '{printf $1}')

     #if its equal to PID then we have a new snapshot
     #SUM variable is to prevent writing to result file before calculating cpu% the first time we have a snapshot   
     if [[ "$TMP" == "PID"  && "$SUM" == "NEWVM" ]] ; then
        #increment snapshot number
        let count++
        echo "$count $VM $NUM" >> result
        NUM="0" 
     fi

     #if we have a number so its the pid of a process
     if [[ $TMP  =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
        #get cpu value
        NEWNUM=$(echo $line | awk '{printf ("%f\n",$9)}')
        #add new value to previous ones
        NUM=$( echo "$NUM $NEWNUM" | awk '{print $1 + $2}')
        SUM="NEWVM"
     fi

done < /home/user/top_VM.txt
#Save cpu usage for the last snapshot
let count++
echo "$count $VM $NUM" >> result
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Here is a part of the top_VM.txt 
http://pastebin.com/R8CrbakW

I do not want to add up the complete 9th column. I want to add up %CPU for each top snapshot. That means in the end I should end up with a table of sums.

Comment: Actually the 9th column in your file is the CPU% :)

Comment: Yes but that is not the problem, the problem is that I run TOP in batch mode, so it will save snapshots every 0.5 seconds. Now I want to have the total CPU usage of each of those snapshots. With your idea it will add up all the values in the 9th column. I do not want that. I want to get a table that shows me the sum of %CPU of each snapshot that is saved in the top_VM.txt (see the pastebin link). It basically has to start adding up values below the %CPU text and stop as soon as it reaches a blank space in that column and then repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your script works perfectly although it seems to be a bit slow.

Comment: Cool so you're going to accept this answer finally :D ,you are welcome, it's because of the read (line by line), i can advice you to split your file into a file by snapshot, then call awk on each snapshot as described in my previous answer.

Comment: Is there any other way to make this process faster? Could I directly convert my TOP output into the sum ? Something like `top -b -d 0.5 | awk '{sum+=$9} END {print sum}' /home/user/top_VM.txt`

Comment: Sure you can, you need to take a snapshot then grep the first 4 lines then calculate the cpu usage. in other words  ` top -n 1 | sed -e '1,4d' | awk '{ sum+=$9} END {print sum}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter for each loop and use the END block. Basically it's like this:

```
awk '{ print $9; sum += $9 } END { print "Sum:", sum }' /home/user/top_VM.txt
```

You can can consider `printf` as well. See [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).